# How can I pass a return value of a Function to another Function as Parameter?

Tags: php, scope, arguments, function-calls

How to pass a value returned by one `function` to another `function`.

```
function myFunction(){
    $a = "Hello World";
    return $a;
}

function anotherFunction(????){
    //how can I call the return value of myFunction() as parameter in this function?
}
```

Comment: use nested function - function myFunction(){
   $a = "Hello World";
anotherFunction( $a )
   //
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got 2 choices:

1. save your return value in a parameter e.g.

   `$value = myFunction();
   anotherFunction ($value);`
2. `anotherFunction ( myFunction() );`

Answer (score 1):

Here's how:

```
<?php

function myFunction() {
    $a = "Hello World";

    return $a;
}

function anotherFunction( $yourvariable ) {
    //how can I call the return value of myFunction() as parameter in this function?
}

$myFunction = myFunction();

$anotherFunction = anotherFunction( $myFunction );
```

Answer (score 1):

[PHP code demo](https://eval.in/765142)

```
<?php
function myFunction(){
   $a = "Hello World";
   return $a;
}

function anotherFunction($requiredParameter)
{
   echo $requiredParameter; //here you will see your parameter.
}


function someOtherFunction()
{
    anotherFunction(myFunction());
}
someOtherFunction();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this call to pass return to another:

```
anotherFunction(myFunction());
```

And anotherFunction you need declare as below:

```
function anotherFunction($val) {
    // your code here
}
```

This will pass return value of myFunction into $val parameter.

Hope this help you!